# Microphone angled waterproofing

Tags: fluid-mechanics, waterproofing, audio-engineering, sound-isolation

We are working on a mounted screen design that will have microphones at the bottom of the screen housing. The screen housing will be sitting at a 10.5 degree angle. So we are worried about water sitting in the microphone hole and not giving us good microphone quality. I have included an image below showing the design. I am stumped and cant think of another way to fix the water not being able to drain out of the hole because of the angle. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Is draining to the right side of the pink wall acceptable?

Comment: no we cant have any water get inside the right side area. That is the inside where are components will be located.

Comment: somewhat related [question about waterproofing a pressure sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331957/waterproof-and-pressure-sensor)

Answer (score 2):

You could make a water drain trap. Drill a vertical hole that meets the microphone hole somewhere along its length, with a drain hole sloping down for the water to escape. You could then make a step change in diameter in the mike hole (for example between the pink and blue parts in our drawing) to stop the water getting past the drain.

Since you appear to have several parts assembled together, you should be able to figure out a way to make something like that - but there isn't enough information on the single view in your drawing to make a useful guess at how to do it!

Comment: several options : good going !

Answer (score 1):

Why have the hole perpendicular to the front surface?

Angle the hole so that it is slightly uphill when the screen is at the angle as shown.

Or, could you fit a membrane on the surface of the microphone and mount it closer to the front face with a larger hole for the entry rhs but smaller hole on the face lhs.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify any dimensions but assuming the waveguide is small enough to act as a capillary, a membrane to prevent water entering it is your only option.